# Using aggregation in MongoDB to select two or more fields of a document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm starting to work with MongoDB and I've a question about aggregation. I've a document that use a lot of different fields in different orders. For example:

```
db.my_collection.insert({ "answers" : [ { "id" : "0", "type" : "text", "value" : "A"}, { "id" : "1", "type" : "text", "value" : "B"}]})


db.my_collection.insert({ "answers" : [ { "id" : "0", "type" : "text", "value" : "C"}, { "id" : "1", "type" : "text", "value" : "A"}]})
```

I would to execute a query using "answers.id" with "answers.value" to obtain a result.

I tried but didn't get results, in my case, I executed the command:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate({$match: {"answers.id":"0", "answers.value": "A"}})
```

And the result was the two responses when I expected only:

```
{ "answers" : [ { "id" : "0", "type" : "text", "value" : "A"}, { "id" : "1", "type" : "text", "value" : "B"}]
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/) operator to match a single element of the `answers` array with both the specified 'id' and 'value'.

Something like this should work:

```js
db.my_collection.aggregate( {
        "$match" : { 
             "answers" { 
                 "$elemMatch" : { 
                        "id" : "0", 
                        "value" : "A"
                 }
             }
         } 
} )
```

Comment: If I want to sort the strings as I do? I tried to follow his model, but he says that is wrong, I tried the following way:

db.my_collection.aggregate ( {$sort: {"answers": {"$ elemMatch": {id: 0, value: -1}}}})

I would like to order the id = 0 in a decreasing manner.

Thanks

Comment: I created a topic in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820532/using-aggregation-to-sorting-in-complex-conditional